# env variable in perl

Tags: perl, environment-variables, remote-access

how do i set environment variable in perl on a remote machine?

I ssh into the remote machine and then try tu set environment variable through export command. 
But it does not set environment variable

```
`ssh -2A root@x.x.x.x`;
`export someEnv=no`;
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f This is similar

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -2A root@x.x.x.x 'someEnv=no script.pl'
```

Answer (score 1):

ssh -2A root@x.x.x.x "export VAR=value && ./script.pl"